# Suma total hasta fecha actual con DataTables

Tags: javascript, datatables

Tengo una tabla creada con datatables, la cual en el footer suma el total de los registros:

| Dia | Cantidad | Precio |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 20 | 2350 |
| 2 | 6 | 1150 |
| 3 | 11 | 630 |
| 4 | 18 | 210 |
| 5 | 15 | 7780 |
| Total | 70 | 12120 |

La fila *Total* se calcula con datatables con `footerCallback` para las columnas con clase `.dt-formater`:

```
"footerCallback": function(tfoot, data, start, end, display) {
        var numFormat = $.fn.dataTable.render.number('.', ',', 0).display;
        var api = this.api();
        api.columns('.dt-formater').every(function () {
            var sum = api
                .cells( null, this.index() )
                .render()
                .reduce(function (a, b) {
                    total = 0;
                    var x = parseInt(a) || 0;
                    var y = parseInt(b) || 0;
                    total = x + y;
                        return total;
                }, 0);
            $(api.column( this.index() ).footer()).html(numFormat(sum));

        });

    }
```

El detalle es que ahora necesito agregar una fila más al footer, la cual calcule la suma total, pero hasta el día actual, pero no logro poder realizarlo. El footer debiese quedar así más o menos:

| Dia | Cantidad | Precio |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 20 | 2350 |
| 2 | 6 | 1150 |
| 3 | 11 | 630 |
| 4 | 18 | 210 |
| 5 | 15 | 7780 |
| Total | 70 | 12120 |
| Total al dia 2 | 26 | 3500 |

Básicamente, necesito ayuda en poder hacer el cálculo hasta el día específico, ya que he investigado y no logro dar con algo que me sirva.

Comment: Por favor, puedes mostrar el código de como obtienes los datos de la tabla? Gracias

Comment: Los datos los despliego directo con php, por eso es que utilizo api para obtener los datos desde la tabla y hacer el calculo.

Answer (score 0):

Logre un acercamiento al requerimiento que necesito.

Dentro de la funcion `api.cloumns()`, agregue un nuevo calculo, aparte de sum, el cual hace el calculo hasta que la celda de dia sea menor o igual al dia actual:

```
api.columns('.dt-formater').every(function () {
            cont = 0;
            
            // Total hasta dia actual
            var sumDiaActual = api
                .cells( null, this.index() )
                .render()
                .reduce(function (a, b) {
                    // Obtengo el valor de la columna dia, en la posicion de la celda, utilizando la variable cont
                    celdaDia = $('#tCopiasComparativaFact tbody tr').eq(cont).find("td").html();
                    // Comparo, si el valor de la celda es menor al de la variable diaActual (Que se obtiene utilizando la funcion de Date()), aplico la suma
                    if ( celdaDia <= diaActual ) {
                        total = 0;
                        var x = parseInt(a) || 0;
                        var y = parseInt(b) || 0;
                        total = x + y;
                    }
                    cont++;
                        return total;
                }, 0);
            
            // Muestra Anexo Totales
            $('#anexoTotales th:eq('+this.index()+')').html( numFormat(sumDiaActual) );

        });
```

Se que se puede mejorar aun mas, pero por lo menos me ayuda a salir del paso. Si alguien tiene algo mas optimizado, seria de gran ayuda.